# Replacing a part of text inside a td

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `td` with this format:

```
<td>
    Business Owner - Delivery Director <br>
    <a href="mailto:me@business.com">me@business.com</a>
</td>
```

How can I only replace the text `"Business Owner - Delivery Director"` with something else?

Using this.text() fetches `Business Owner - Delivery Director` and `me@business.com`, but I  want only
`Business Owner - Delivery Director.`

Comment: Don't use jQuery. Get the text node!

Comment: do you essentially want a string between <td> and <br> ? A simple regex can do it for you.

Comment: @Scorpion: No. The OP does not want to manipulate the HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to get the text node (with [`CharacterData` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/CharacterData)) and then manipulate its content:

```
$("td").contents()[0].data = "Businees Owner (CEO)";
```

[Demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/z28Ts/)

Comment: +1 as this is the most readable solution out there that works for the OP's current html.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.childNodes) property to select the first text node and change its value:

```
$('td')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue = "New content";
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/dpyNy/

Comment: +1 Very useful to remind people that text nodes exist! jQuery tends to obscure that...

Answer (score 1):

With *that* structure, you'll have to do string manipulation, either using `split`:

```
var td = $("selector_for_the_td_element");
var text = td.html().split("<br>");
text[0] = "new content";
td.html(text.join("<br>"));
```

...or using `indexOf` and `substring`:

```
var td = $("selector_for_the_td_element");
var text = td.html();
var index = text.indexOf("<br>");
text = "new content" + text.substring(index);
td.html(text);
```

Now, if you can change your HTML structure to this:

```
<td>
    <span>Business Owner - Delivery Director</span><br>
    <a href="mailto:me@business.com">me@business.com</a>
</td>
```

...it gets a lot easier:

```
$("selector_for_the_td_element > span").text("new content");
```

Comment: @Bergi: That's how I read it. *"How can I only replace the text..."* and *"`this.text() gives me..."*. Granted this is possible using the text nodes, but as he's clearly using jQuery, a jQuery-oriented solution's reasonable. (Upvoted Asad for the other, though.)

Comment: @Bergi: The OP hasn't mentioned any preference in regards to "HTML manipulation".
T.J: I like the `span` suggestion, good practice.

Answer (score -1):

If the html structure is exactlly what you post, you can achieve it like this:

```
this.childNodes[0].nodeValue = 'hello'; //this is the td element
```

Comment: I assume you mean the `td` with `this`, but that's a pretty poor choice of variable names.

Comment: @Cerbrus It's not a variable name and 'this' cannot be a variable name in javascript, i just write it following the context in the question , maybe it's in an event handler environment, why can you say it's a poor name just according to this snippet?

Comment: Oh, I missed the `this` in his question. Forget I said anything :-P