# Substring not working on childNodes[0].nodeValue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to extract a text from td as discussed here 
[Replacing a part of text inside a td](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760664/replacing-a-part-of-text-inside-a-td#13760705)

```
$('.my-table tr').each(function() {

     var contact = $(this).find('td').eq(1)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
     $(this).find('td').eq(1).contents()[0].data = contact.substring(0,10);
});
```

But contact.substring(0,10); doesn't seem to work and it just shows empty.

How can i fix this?

Comment: 1/ are you sure there is something in "contact" ? 2/ are you sure your find.eq.contents.data works ?

Comment: this is impossible to answer without seeing the related markup. there's too much going on here that could go wrong to guess.

Comment: What exactly is the data property on the last line doing? And why are you using eq() when you get the native element in the next statement?

Comment: Markup.. <td>
          Business Owner - Delivery Director <br>
          <a href="mailto:me@business.com">me@business.com</a>
        </td>

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935689/what-is-the-difference-between-children-and-childnodes-in-javascript

Comment: yes contact = $(this).find('td').eq(1)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue; works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
$('.my-table tr').each(function() {

     var contact = $.trim($(this).find('td').eq(1)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
     if(contact != '')
     {
         var value = contact.substring(0,10);
         alert(value);
         $(this).find('td').eq(1).contents()[0].data = contact.substring(0,10);
     }
});
```

What is the alert value you are getting?? or are you getting any alerts??

Comment: palash when i do console.log(contact) its shows me the contact but alert(value) still returns me empty..

Comment: Business34 Owner - Manager

Comment: there is a space in start of the text.

Comment: i tried this  var contact = ($(this).find('td').eq(1)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue).trim(); seems to fix the issue probably lot of spacing at the start.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `.eq(1)[0]`, but just [`.get(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to get plain DOM nodes. Also, don't use two different ways of obtaining the same text node, but only one and store it in a variable. Let's check what has happened:

```
$('.my-table tr').each(function() {

     var cell = $('td', this);
     if (!cell.length)
         return alert("Could not find a table cell");

     var el = cell.get(0);
     if (!el) alert("Could not get first element"); // Won't happen if length was >0

     if (!el.childNodes.length)
         return alert("Cell is empty!");

     var text = el.childNodes[0];
     if (cell.contents()[0] != text) alert("different firstChilds???"); // Won't happen
     if (text.nodeType != 3)
         return alert("the first child node is not a text node!");

     var contact = text.nodeValue;
     if (text.data != contact) alert("different contents???"); // Won't happen
     if (typeof contact != "string") alert("content is no string"); // Won't happen

     var newcontact = contact.substring(0,10);
     alert('"'+contact+'" was changed to "'+newcontact+'"');
     text.data = newcontact;
});
```

([Demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/z28Ts/1/))

Answer (score 0):

First of all does contact holds what you need? I mean did you console.log `contact` value?

If contact is ok then try something like this:

```
var contact = new String($(this).find('td').eq(1)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```